Deserializing associative array with Symfony Serializer
I am trying to deserialize an associative array into array of objects with a string-key.
{
"en": {
  "name": "Name of product"
},
"ar": {
  "name": "Name of product in arabic"
}
}

I have a class Catalog, where product translations stored in array with a locale as a key.
Symfony serializer returns me an error: The type of the key "ru" must be "int" ("string" given).
Symfony 7.1 is used.
The incoming payload comes from serializing Doctrine Collection with indexBy attribute.
How can I set an type of key for specific field in my class?
Thanks a lot,
Best regards,
Oleg

Look at the Doctrine annotation and field annotations

If it's not possible to deserialize the array with annotations, you can use callbacks, see (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances) to deserialize nested arrays.

So there is no any attribute I can assign to an property (that is array) to set the type of the key. I was looking into source code of ArrayDeserializer, it check the type of the key by key_type context parameter. But if I set it in the Context attribute, it is not read.
Also, I am not using Doctrine bundle on the receiving side.

This is possible if you'll use PhpDocExtractor() insted or in addition to ReflectionExtractor().
So to provide information about array key to Serializer all you need is annotate your array property with type description like this:
/** @var array<string, yourValueType> $arrayProperty */
note: that annotation must begin with /** (not /*)

So what PhpDocExtractor does, it parses the source code of your class.
Which may not be that efficient as gathering information from reflection.
But it definitely will work as you expecting.
PS:
My question to the next generations of people is:
How to do this without PhpDocExtractor() ?

I have approached a potential solution to this via testing.
When deserializing via json_decode an stdClass is used to store all the values. You can imagine this being a dynamic like from C#.
To get an idea of how to access properties take a look at the the assertions.
When deserializing via SerializerInterface::deserialize() a container class Language is used to provide the properties.
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Functional;

use stdClass;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class Language
{
    public string $name;
}

class DeserializeAssocTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function test_via_json_decode(): void
    {
        $json = self::createJsonString();
        $catalog = json_decode($json);

        //var_dump($catalog);

        self::assertInstanceOf(stdClass::class, $catalog);
        self::assertStringContainsString('Arabic', $catalog->ar->name);
    }

    public function test_via_symfony_serializer(): void
    {
        $serializer = self::getContainer()->get(SerializerInterface::class);        
        $json = self::createJsonString();
        $catalog = $serializer->deserialize($json, Language::class . '[]', 'json');

        //var_dump($catalog);

        self::assertIsArray($catalog);
        self::assertInstanceOf(Language::class, $catalog['ar']);        
        self::assertStringContainsString('Arabic', $catalog['ar']->name);
    }

    private static function createJsonString(): string
    {
        $data = [
            'en' => ['name' => 'Name of product'],
            'ar' => ['name' => 'Name of product in Arabic'],
        ];

        $serializer = self::getContainer()->get(SerializerInterface::class);
        assert($serializer instanceof SerializerInterface);

        $json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

        self::assertJson($json);

        return $json;
    }
}

